# Sumar días a la variable _endDate tipo DateTime, del objeto DateRangePicker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Me gustaría sumar una cantidad `n` de días a una variable tipo DateTime llamada `_endDate`, cuando selecciono en el calendario el día inicial `_startDate`, automáticamente se le sume una cantidad de días `n` a la variable final `_endDate`, un ejemplo: selecciono el día 01/01/2020, pues una vez asignada valor a la inicial sumar 5 días dando como valor final 05/01/2020, pues ese sería el rango de fecha seleccionado para el objeto `DateRagePicker`.

Paso el código de la función:

```
newVacaciones(BuildContext context) async {

final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialFirstDate: _startDate,
    initialLastDate: _endDate,
    firstDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 1),
    lastDate: new DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1));

if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
  setState(() {
    _startDate = picked[0];
    _endDate = picked[1];
  });
}
```

Comment: Puedes convertir _picked[1] en milisegundos y sumarle los 5 dias (en milisegundos) y almacenarlo como fecha _endDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar esto:

```
void incrementDays(int daysToIncrement) {
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime.now();
  print(dateTime.day);
  
  dateTime = dateTime.add(Duration(days: daysToIncrement));
  print(dateTime.day);
```

Lo único que debes hacer es adaptarlo a lo que tú tienes y utilizar el _endDate en lugar de utilizar el dateTime que puse en el ejemplo.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

puede utilizar la siguiente función teniendo en cuenta

para resta fechas

```
fechaActualD.subtract(Duration(days: diasResta));
```

para sumar fechas

```
fechaActualD.add(Duration(days: diasResta));

 
el valor de Duration puede se definidor por 
const Duration(
      {int days = 0,
      int hours = 0,
      int minutes = 0,
      int seconds = 0,
      int milliseconds = 0,
      int microseconds = 0})
```

función completa

```
//int diasResta=10;
restaFecha(int diasResta) async {
  String fechaActual = '2022-01-15';
  DateTime fechaActualD = DateTime.parse(fechaActual);
  // DateTime dateTime = new DateTime.now();
  fechaActualD = fechaActualD.subtract(Duration(days: diasResta));
  String inputFecha = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(fechaActualD);
  return inputFecha;//salida 2022-01-05
}
```